# Coremetrics files / Unstructure data in Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I need to load Coremetrics files / Unstructured data in Google Cloud.

What are options I have to do that? Manual / automated.
What are options to read from unstructured data

Thanks you input

Comment: could you provide more information about what are those files and what you want to do with them: to process, to store, ...?

Answer (score 0):

Coremetrics provides three good ways to do this (depending on your need):
Export tool, LIVEmail, and the DDX API which can also export data. The documentation for each is in the Coremetrics tool under "Help".